# using PredicateBuilder inside a select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm creating an Ad-hoc report feature for my application.
I used the PredicateBuilder for the "Where" part but now when I'm trying to use it also inside the "Select" part I can't succeed.

Sample of the code:

```
   IQueryable<User> usersQuery = db.Users.AsQueryable();

    var where = PredicateBuilder.True<User>();
    //sample for the users query
    where = where.And(p => p.Enabled);


    var selectOrders = PredicateBuilder.True<UserOrder>();
    //sample for a query inside user orders
    selectOrders = selectOrders.And(p => p.Amount > 10);

    usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(where); //work
    var query = (from a in usersQuery
         select new
                {
                FirstName = a.FirstName,
                TotalOrders = a.UserOrders.Where(selectOrders).Count() //could not compile                                                                                               
                }).AsQueryable();
```

I don't think you can do

```
.Select("new (TotalOrders = UserOrders.Where(BetAmount > @0).Count()")
```

In DynamicLinq but I can't use it cause I call some sql user defined functions inside the 'select' and DynamicLinq doesn't support it.

Comment: What compilation error you get?

Comment: the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage

I'm passing Expression<Func<UserOrder, bool>> (selectOrders) where I should pass only Func<UserOrder, bool>

Comment: What type is your a.UserOrders? if it's IEnumerable (not IQuerybale) then try a.UserOrders.AsQueryable().Where(selectOrders).Count()

Comment: Its compiling but I get "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem here lies in fact, that Linq to SQL doesnt support subqueries, which would be required by your query. Thats why navigational properties `UserOrders` in your case doesn't implement `IQueryable` and queries can't be run on it.

I might be wrong.
But this proves me right : http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2009/01/why-linq-to-sql-is-not-proper-orm.html

You should use better ORM like Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

What about a workaround like this? You have change the join condition according to your schema

```
var where = PredicateBuilder.True<User>();
//sample for the users query
where = where.And(p => p.Enabled);

var selectOrders = PredicateBuilder.True<UserOrder>();
//sample for a query inside user orders
selectOrders = selectOrders.And(p => p.Amount > 10);

var usersQuery = from u in db.Users.Where(where)
                 join o in db.UserOrders.Where(selectOrders) 
                        on u.UserId equals o.UserId
                 group o by u into groupedOrders
                 select new
                 {
                    FirstName = groupedOrders.Key.FirstName,
                    TotalOrders = groupedOrders.Count()                                                                                              
                 };
```

Comment: But then it changes the query. FirstName and TotalOrders are only few fields from a big list with fields and their own query and even group by